# How load libraries in Python use VSC

Tags: python, kaggle

Im want replicate this code of Kaggle but don't run in Visual Studio Code. Im want run in VSC

https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/hello-seaborn

[image]

How solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Miguel :) Remove the `%matplotlib inline`. Your code should look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
print('setup complete')
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: * Im R user but I need learn py.*Im run this but show this error:

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\macosta\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.